# Monitoring custom Stream apps in Spring Cloud data flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying scdf and its monitoring with prometheus and grafana. I followed the documentation available and able to deploy the sample stream and able to see the metrics in the grafana.

I have created a stream with some custom stream app (other than the supplied rabbit mq starter apps).

Stream: 
htt | participant | log

But am not able see the "participant" application metrics in gafana. But able to see the metrics of http and log apps.

Added below properties in application.properties.

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
spring.cloud.streamapp.security.enabled=false
```

Added below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud.stream.app/app-starters-common &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>app-starters-common</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>-->
        <!--<type>pom</type>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

After adding app-starters-common:org.springframework.cloud.stream.app dependency localhost:< port >/ opens a login page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `app-starters-micrometer-common` dependency which [adds](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/core/blob/master/common/app-starters-micrometer-common/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories) some of the micrometer tags to your app. This dependency is intended to be used by the Spring cloud stream app starters and I believe you can use it in your custom application as well.

Comment: I have added the `app-starters-micrometer-common` dependency, but still no luck. After this http://localhost:25340/actuator endpoint is showing a login page.

Comment: I have added below in the application properties. but still showing the logic page.
`security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false`
How to disable the security.  ?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while looking answers for the same.

Here is my working code snippet:-

### Pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-jmx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application property change to enable prometheus and disable security(login page)

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
```

-- this one to remove security (login page), which was automatically added by app-starter-micrometre-common dependency.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

or

exclude the dependency, I excluded config-client and few other since I don't need them in my application.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

With later Data Flow 2.3.x, you need to add the following dependencies to your processor:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
    <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The `app-starters-micrometer-common` injects DataFlow specific tags, such as `stream.name`, `application.name`, `application.type` all used by the dashboard to aggregate the required metrics.

In addition you can follow instructions in the sample projects, showing  how to build custom `Source`, `Processor` and `Sink` apps with enabled prometheus monitoring: 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/monitoring-samples/stream-apps