# SCDF metrics for custom docker stream apps in local deployment

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

In a docker-compose local deployment with Prometheus + grafana, I am trying to deploy custom docker kafka source and sink as `foo | bar`

Both deploy fine and sink is receiving data from source as expected. However when I try to go to grafana to get the kafka metrics I see no data

I tried following the [monitoring sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/monitoring-samples/stream-apps) and a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166800/monitoring-custom-stream-apps-in-spring-cloud-data-flow) in stackoverflow, to no avail

My dependencies are

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-jmx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>app-starters-micrometer-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>prometheus-rsocket-spring</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

My application.yml

```
management:
  health:
    binders:
      enabled: true
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: always
    bindings:
      enabled: true
    env:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  info:
    defaults:
      enabled: true

spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Looking at my apps' logs I see

```
stderr:
io.rsocket.exceptions.ConnectionErrorException: No keep-alive acks for 90000 ms
    at io.rsocket.RSocketRequester.terminate(RSocketRequester.java:115)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport.tryTimeout(KeepAliveSupport.java:110)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport$ClientKeepAliveSupport.onIntervalTick(KeepAliveSupport.java:146)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport.lambda$start$0(KeepAliveSupport.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxInterval$IntervalRunnable.run(FluxInterval.java:123)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.call(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:59)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.run(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
io.rsocket.exceptions.ConnectionErrorException: No keep-alive acks for 90000 ms
    at io.rsocket.RSocketRequester.terminate(RSocketRequester.java:115)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport.tryTimeout(KeepAliveSupport.java:110)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport$ClientKeepAliveSupport.onIntervalTick(KeepAliveSupport.java:146)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport.lambda$start$0(KeepAliveSupport.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxInterval$IntervalRunnable.run(FluxInterval.java:123)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.call(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:59)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.run(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
io.rsocket.exceptions.ConnectionErrorException: No keep-alive acks for 90000 ms
    at io.rsocket.RSocketRequester.terminate(RSocketRequester.java:115)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport.tryTimeout(KeepAliveSupport.java:110)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport$ClientKeepAliveSupport.onIntervalTick(KeepAliveSupport.java:146)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport.lambda$start$0(KeepAliveSupport.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxInterval$IntervalRunnable.run(FluxInterval.java:123)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.call(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:59)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.run(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
io.rsocket.exceptions.ConnectionErrorException: No keep-alive acks for 90000 ms
    at io.rsocket.RSocketRequester.terminate(RSocketRequester.java:115)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport.tryTimeout(KeepAliveSupport.java:110)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport$ClientKeepAliveSupport.onIntervalTick(KeepAliveSupport.java:146)
    at io.rsocket.keepalive.KeepAliveSupport.lambda$start$0(KeepAliveSupport.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxInterval$IntervalRunnable.run(FluxInterval.java:123)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.call(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:59)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.PeriodicWorkerTask.run(PeriodicWorkerTask.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However If I use one of the included apps such that `time | bar` I see the data for time in grafana which tells me this is not a docker issue (also I am able to ping from my prometheus-rsocket-proxy container to my bar container and back)

Any ideas on this matter would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The sample is on older versions, but that should still work, though.

We have added a few GH templates to build new custom apps with [Rabbit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/dataflow-app-rabbit) and [Kafka](https://github.com/spring-cloud/dataflow-app-kafka) binders. That should automatically bring in the right dependencies to help you get up and running with monitoring, too.

Give this a go and let us know in the template repo if you still see any issues.

Comment: Thansks for that, @SabbyAnandan. For now I opted for influxdb so just switching
`micrometer-registry-prometheus`
with
`micrometer-registry-influx`
works fine. I will look into the examples to see  what I did wrong for Prometheus